# How to handle the first request in an Angular and Django app

Tags: python, django, angularjs, url

I have a issue. My home state url is `'/'`, but also in Django my home url is `'/'`

```
$stateProvider
.state("home",{
  url:"/",
  controller:'HomeController',
  resolve:{
    cities:getAvailbleCities
  },
})
```

My urls.py

```
url(r'^/*$', 'landing.views.landing', name='home'),
```

My base href

```
<base href="/">
```

So, when I visit `localhost:8000/`, angular catch the request, execute `HomeController` but my server also catch the request and it cause a redirect and the page is refreshed and all my changes inside `HomeController` are gone.

How should I handle the `/` url without making any conflict.

Or there is another way to fetch initial data from django server.

Note: I need in somehow reach the server, because I need django initial data(`crsf cookies`,etc). So removing url home rule does not work for me.

Comment: Have you considered serving your root HTML file that loads your Angular app separately from the view that returns the initial data via ajax?

Comment: or setting the initial data as a JavaScript object from the server side when `/` is requested?

Comment: @Brandon but for do it that, I would have to change my root url from `/` to something else and that is not quite good. Because user couldn't enter to app using a normal url likes `www.mysite.com/`

Comment: Why? If your Django view is serving your initial HTML, you're in complete control of the rendered response. You could easily add your initial data, or pull in the initial data via ajax at any URL you want without affecting the entry URL.